# What regexp do I use in htaccess RewriteRule to match % in a URI?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a user types this into a browser: 
http://cauzoom.com/collection/something0%d
I want them to end up here:
http://cauzoom.com/collection/index.html?pname=something

My current htaccess rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^collection/([a-z0-9\-\%]+)$ collection/index.html?pname=$1 [NC,L]
```

... but that fails. When I do this:

```
RewriteRule ^collection/(.+)$ collection/index.html?pname=$1 [NC,L]
```

... it also fails. I know % is a protected regexp character, but putting the literal "\" in front of it SHOULD work, right? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` isn't a regular expression metacharacter, the problem is that it's used to encode characters in URLs, so you can't just use a literal `%` in an URL as it's meant to start a sequence which identifies a special character: [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

If you want to have a real `%` in an URL you have to encode it as `%25`.

Comment: http://cauzoom.com/collection/something0%d was a link mistakenly sent out in an email to a big group. The group is clicking on it and the link is failing. I was trying to write something to fix the error. Is there any way to write a RewriteRule to match 'something0%d' and *fix* it so it ends up in the right place?

Comment: Nope that link is broken **before** it gets to the server